# How to read from xlsx file and storing specific column values into an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, regression

Hello community I am trying to figure out how I can read data from a xlsx file and store it into an array. What is the best library I can download to do this on python27?

I am trying to figure out how i can read a specific column, get the values from the column to a certain cell and then storing it into an array?

Example: For my linear regression analysis I have one Y variable and a multivariable X equation.

The Y values will be read from a specific column

ex:

```
y= [1,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,6,5,4,5,4,3,4] #<-specific column
```

where as the multi variable X values will be read data values from multiple columns

ex:

```
 x = [
    [4,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,7,4,8,9,8,8,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],      #<-specific column
     [4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,8,7,8,7,8,7,8,7,7,7,7,7,6,5],      #<-specific column
     [4,1,2,5,6,7,8,9,7,8,7,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,4,4,4]       #<-specific column
     ]
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have Excel on that machine?

Comment: I do have excel on the machine

Comment: You could use `openpyxl`, as suggested, but I've found it buggy. So if you can use Excel to do the job just use Excel. Or export to csv and use a module called `csv` directly. Some info how to use Excel from Python: http://pythonexcels.com/basic-excel-driving-with-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is really useful for this type of manipulation.

```
import pandas as pd
xl_workbook = pd.ExcelFile("my_data.xlsx")  # Load the excel workbook
df = xl_workbook.parse("Sheet 1")  # Parse the sheet into a dataframe
x1_list = df['x1'].tolist()  # Cast the desired column into a python list
```

Specifically, when you call the df by the column index it returns a Numpy series, and the .tolist() coerces it into a python list.

Comment: Learning to use Pandas, or starting to use it, is probably far more  useful than `Win32Com`, especially if you're planning on working with a lot of data in the future. Although, the latter **is** very useful too. `openpyxl`, on the other hand, is more or less useless, unless you have a very strong incentive to use OpenOffice Calc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [openpyxl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) and should find all needed information in their [documenation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Win32Com](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). I've used it with python 2.7 to work with Excel and Word files.